# CSS/HTML Background, new picture when scrolling

Tags: html, css, background, positioning

I'm working on [this website][1]. I have a "mainbackground" which is shown on it.

Is it possible to make [this picture][2] continue when you scroll?

Here's my CSS:

```
background-image: url("bakgrund.jpg")
```

Comment: And why -1 without a reason?

Comment: I Googled your question title and the first and second results solved your problem.

Comment: No, cause its not a fixed background i want.

Comment: You want it to repeat?

Comment: I want a new picture to repeat (http://i.imgur.com/X0B4JeD.jpg) or is it easier to just have that one as a background, make the background repeat then have a div tag placing the banner?

Comment: @Pontus Try `background-repeat: repeat;`

Comment: background-repeat: repeat; 
Works! - BUT.. It repeats my background picture with the banner (PONTUS LUNDH).
I want it to be a new picture that repeats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having a little difficulty figuring out exactly how you envision this working.

If you want the background image to continue down the page as far as the content goes, use:

```
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

If you want multiple images as the background, use:

```
background-image: url(image-url-1), url(image-url-2);
```

If you want the image to scroll with the text (i.e., not fixed) **but then continue scrolling** once you reach the end of the content, or if you want to dynamically load in multiple images as the need arises, you would need to do it programmatically using AJAX or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: No, cause its a blog. I cant have it scroll like that.. That would mean you would have such a small space to read stuff on..

Comment: I understand, but how else would you see it work? If the images' height is smaller than the page height it will cut off at some point.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that.. Thats why im wondering if you can make it scroll, scroll, scroll with a new background.. Then sure, it might look stupid.. But thats what im wondering.

Comment: In your current configuration it would be difficult. I suggest rethinking your layout. For example using only the blue canvas as the background image and then have a sidebar element on the left (which will include the photos image) and a content header element on the right above the text (which would include the banner image). This way the images would scroll with the text and the blue canvas pattern will remain on the background at all times. I think that's the best effect you could hope for (using one image after another will look unprofessional and in some cases downright weird).

Comment: ..yeah probably.. I'll stick with that then.
I understand people saying Attachement: fixed.
I get the point with it. So yeah, i'll guess i'll think over the design.. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying for a fixed background try this http://jsfiddle.net/kkmLpqqd/

```
<div id="a">a</div>

#a{
width:300px;
height:2000px;
background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/300/301);
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: That causes it to be fixed tho.
Imagine, i want a new picture to continue where the current one is..
Its not a fixed one i want.. I want you to be able to scroll down endlessly and the background staying where it is.

Comment: @Pontus That's what `background: fixed;` does. It keeps the background frozen in place while the site content continues to scroll.

Comment: @Pontus show some of your code or try repeat-y so that it will repeat

Comment: So there is no way I can have it the way it is now, with a new background continueing where my current one ends now?

If i add "bakcrground-attachment: fixed;"
The entire text goes up over the banner and stuff.. Like, i want it to stay. And I want the page to scroll down with a new background, i dont want the text to scroll. I want the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
.class-name { 
  background:url(your-image.jpg) no-repeat; 
  background-attachment: fixed;
 }
```

http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position-background-image

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the background image to the "body" element in the CSS, and then put all of the content you need to scroll in a "container" div, with a white background (or whatever you'd like).

```
css:
body {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: ...
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #FFF;
}

html:
<body>
    <div id="container>
       ...
    </div>
</body>
```